# Necessary and sufficient condition of $S$-Noetherian rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

I've read Proposition 4 and Corollary 5 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243046167_S-Noetherian_rings).

> Proposition 4
> Let $R$ be a ring, $ S \subseteq R$ a multiplicative set and $M$ an $S$-finite $R$-module. Then $M$ is $S$ Noetherian if and only if the submodule of the form $PM$ are $S$-finite for each prime ideal $P$ of $R$ (disjoint from $S$).
>
> Corollary 5
> Let $R$ be a ring and $S\subseteq R$ a multiplicative set. Then $R$ is $S$-Noetherian if and only if every prime ideal of $R$ (disjoint from $S$) is $S$-finite.

I've proved Proposition 4 and I want to prove Corollary 5. I can't do that because in Proposition 4, $M$ is $S$-finite, but in Corollary 5, it didn't say anything about $S$-finiteness of $R$. Is every commutative ring could be $S$-finite ?

Comment: Any finitely generated $R$-module is $S$-finite for all multiplicative sets $S$. In fact, $R$ itself is principal and thus $S$-principal. (p. 4408, line -5, "all rings are commutative with identity")

Comment: Sorry, why $R$ is principal ?

Comment: The ideal generated by $1_R$, the identity, is $R$. This is a piece of background knowledge one would be expected to have going into the paper; you should read a textbook on commutative algebra first.

Comment: thankyou very much ^^